# Dirac delta convolution with function

Tags: integration, convolution, dirac-delta

I've come into a bit of a snag, and thought some more talented mathematicians could maybe help.
I am trying to do the following integral:

$$S(x,t) = \int I(z)\delta(x-G(z,t)) \mathrm{d}z,$$

where $G(z,t)$ is a function which 'pushes' the original function $I(z)$ into $S(x,t)$ at some later time.
I've tried using some Dirac delta identities but have not had much success.
Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use the decomposition of the "composite" delta function $\delta(f(x))$,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function

In your case you have
$$\delta(x - G(z,t)) = \sum_{i} \frac{\delta(z-z_i)}{|\partial_z G(z,t)|_{z=z_i}|}$$ 
where the sum goes over the solutions $z_i(x,t)$ of the equation $G(z,t) = x$, so that
$$S(x,t) = \sum_{i} \frac{I(z_i)}{|\partial_z G(z,t)|_{z=z_i}|}$$
Potential problems might arise at points where $\partial_z G(z,t)|_{z=z_i} = 0$.

Answer (score -1):

You'd think of $\int f(x) \delta(x) \; \mathrm{d} x = f(0)$ as picking just the value of $f$ where $\delta$'s argument is zero. I.e., in this case the result is $I(z)$ wherever $G(z, t) = x$.

Comment: Aren't you missing a factor $\partial G/\partial z$?  Also, if there are several values of $z$ for which $G(z,t)=x$, then shouldn't you be adding together all the corresponding values $I(z)$?